# Connect with more than two databases using Django ORM, one database is legacy database without migrate into app

Tags: django-models, django-database, mysql-connector-python

We want to connect a remote existing database from settings.py, can we use those tables directly using model without migrate from app.

We know about the legacy database connection but inspect.db command always asks to migrate the connected database.

Is using mysql connector is preferable or it is out of standard, please suggest.

Thanks, your help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is the `managed` meta option in your models. When you define your models, by default you have `managed=True`. If you want to use an existing database without Django interfering with migrations, you should use **`managed=False`**.

See [this part](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/options/#managed) of the doc:

> [...] If `False`, no database table creation or deletion operations will be performed for this model. This is useful if the model represents an existing table or a database view that has been created by some other means. This is the only difference when `managed=False`. All other aspects of model handling are exactly the same as normal.  [...]